# How to bind form action with a variable?

Tags: html, angular

I have one form action

```
 <form  [formGroup]="onlinepaymentForm" action={{url}} target="_blank" method="POST" #form padding>
 </form>
```

I have to bind  action with a variable,is it possible?

Comment: you should be using `ngSubmit` as the from action

Answer (score 0):

If `url` could be changed later on you should use property binding

```
<form [action]="url">
```

If `url` will remain the same always then use interpolation

```
<form action="{{url}}">
```